# how to fix my parameter so it gets the right value

Tags: c, parameters

I am trying to pass a number an found its root

I tried running this code to an online compiler and I get random numbers that I didn't entered with `scanf`. I tried it on an online compiler that can be found here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#.
For some reason whatever I put I get 8. I also tried it in DEV-C++ which can found here https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ in that complier I always get 0 instead of my input number. There is also printf for confirmation to scanf and seems to me that the value actually becomes my input but when I call the function everything changes any ideas (thanks for ur time)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define g(x,num) 1.0/3.0*(2.0 * x + (num / x)) //f'(x,num)
#define var 1E-10//10^-10
#define f(x,num) x*x - num


double x;
int i;
double num;

void sqrtNR(double num){// **actual bug**

        printf ("\nnum: %d\n", num);
    x = num;
    printf ("x: %d\n", x);

for(i;var < fabs(f(x,num)) ; i++) {  **infinite loop**
    x = x - ( f(x,num)/g(x,num) );
//  printf ("x: %d\n", x);

                                  }
    printf ("metrhths %d\n", i);
return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("dwse ari9mo\n");
    scanf("%lf", & num);
    printf("%lf", num);
    sqrtNR(num);
    //printf("\nsrtNR : %lf", sqrtNR(num));

    }
```

youknow actually get the for at least working cuz now its on infinite loop

Comment: thanks for the edit and sorry for some typos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your printf formats are wrong and cause the UB.

Abstracting from the math logic of your function.

```
void sqrtNR(double num)
{
    printf ("\nnum: %f\n", num);
    x = num;
    printf ("x: %f\n", x);

    while(var < fabs(f(x,num))
    {
        x = x - ( f(x,num)/g(x,num) );                          
    }
    return x;
}
```

you should also put your macro parameters in the parenthesizes